# getting the value of a placeholder using colModel gridparam

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have set a placeholder using below code to my grid datetime fields. Now I want to get this place holder value in another .js file after the request for filter is applied.

```
searchoptions: {
    attr: { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" }
}
```

After entering a date and press enter to filter the grid, in the flow my request reaches to a .js file and in it I want to get the value I kept for the place holder (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm in this case).

From my jqgrid, I am sending colModel gridparam as below.

```
function (e){
    .stopImmediatePropagation();
     filters = $(this).getGridParam('postData').filters;
             colModel = $(this).getGridParam('colModel');
             status = checkValidDateFormat(filters,colModel);
            (status == false){
             'stop';            }
}
```

I am getting the datatype of a field using colModel param as below.

```
attrValue = colModel.dataType||null;
```

Now my requirement is to get the placeholder of the field and I tried to do it as below and it is not working. It's a great help if someone can suggest me in this.

```
attrValue = colModel[i].attr('placeholder')||null;
```

Comment: @Oleg, Hi Oleg! I have created a new question for it. Can you please help me in this matter..

Comment: I see the question now and will try to help you. By the way you should write comment with `@Oleg` somewhere where I posed wither my answer of my comment before. If you opens new question and write comment with `@Oleg` I'll get no notification because stackoverfow will unable to map `Oleg` to one from `Oleg` account on the stackoverflow (see http://stackoverflow.com/users and search for Oleg).

Comment: I'm not sure what function `function (e){...}` is above. Where you use it? By the way `colModel.dataType` is wrong. One can use `.getGridParam('datatype')` for example to get `datatype` of the grid. `colModel` is *array* and you can use `colModel[iCol].searchoptions.attr.placeholder`. Free jqGrid have `iColByName` to simplify getting the column name by the name. Moreover you wrote "I want to get this place holder value in another .js file" without any exact description what you do and which information/code you place in which file. Is it the file with common settings which you include?

Comment: @Oleg: Hi Oleg, the statement in your comment above (i.e. colModel[iCol].searchoptions.attr.placeholder) works for my requirement. Thanks for the help. The function I posted above is just to stop sending the request to the server for filtering any date with unsupported format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colModel[iCol].searchoptions.attr.placeholder` to access the `placeholder`. By the way free jqGrid have `iColByName` parameter, which to simplify getting the column name by the name. You can get the properties `var colModel = $(this).getGridParam('colModel')` and `var iColByName = $(this).getGridParam('iColByName')` and then use `colModel[iColByName[columnName]]` (where `columnName` is the variable with the column name as the value) or `colModel[iColByName.myColName1]` if you knows the column name `name: "myColName1"` statically.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info Oleg! @Oleg. Have one more question, would create a question and comment it with your name. Please help.

Comment: Hi Oleg, can you please look into the following URL and help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016081/css-is-not-applying-jqgrid-view-options?noredirect=1#comment63475220_38016081

Comment: @santoshM: The question has almost no details. It's unclear how `wrap-col` is applied on jqGrid, which version of jqGrid is used and from which fork of jqGrid, ... One write about the problem on "click on that particular cell". It could be that one uses some editing (inline editing or cell editing) and one want to wrap the data during editing, but the `edittype` is unclear too. The comment can suspect that one use `edittype="textarea"`. I have to do my main job and I can't spend many time in clearing what other people really need. The demo with the problem could clear the most things.