# css is not applying jqgrid view options

Tags: css, jqgrid

I am able to get the **complete** data for one particular cell of a row in grid after applying the css implementation for that particular cell as below

```
.wrap-col {
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap!important;
        word-wrap: break-word!important;
        white-space: pre-wrap!important;
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap!important;
        white-space: pre-wrap!important;
    }
```

But when I click on that particular cell to view it, **data is not displaying completely. It is displaying part of the whole message**.

reason I observed is, class name is getting changed from grid to view record.
I provided css definition for id in view record but it is not applying
How can I keep the same class name in the grid as well as view record or is there any other way to get the data when I click to view the row?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML to see the layout?

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: @adamk22, it is not html in my case. It is jqgrid implementation. It looks like this.
<Column name="Error Message" map="status_reason" width="400" type="textarea" search="false" classes="wrap-col" />
Here I added css definition for wrap-col as shown above